# Is there a way to stop scripts that are running simultaneously if one of them send an echo?

Tags: bash

I need to find if a value (actually it's more complex than that) is in one of 20 servers I have. And I need to do it as fast as possible. Right now I am sending the scripts simultaneously to all the servers. My main script is something like this (but with all the servers):

```
#!/bin/sh
#mainScript.sh
value=$1

c1=`cat serverList | sed -n '1p'`
c2=`cat serverList | sed -n '2p'`

sh find.sh $value $c1 & sh find.sh $value $c2


#!/bin/sh
#find.sh

#some code here .....


if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  rm $tempfile
else

myValue=`sed -n '/VALUE/p' $tempfile | awk 'BEGIN{FS="="} {print substr($2, 8, length($2)-2)}'`
echo "$myValue"
fi
```

So the script only returns a response if it finds the value in the server. I would like to know if there is a way to stop executing the other scripts if one of them already return a value.

I tried adding an "exit" on the find.sh script but it won't stop all the scripts. Can somebody please tell me if what I want to do is possible?

Comment: Roughly how long does each server take to check?

Comment: Do you have 20 servers like in your question, or 2 like your code?

Comment: If you are in a rush, `sed` followed by `awk` is two processes and something of an anti-pattern, consider just `awk '/VALUE/{...}' $tempfile` instead.

Comment: If I understand you have `find` running on 20 different servers and if 1 succeeds you want to kill the other 19 running on different machines -- that's not trivial. You will have to have one server (master) hold a list of the hosts/PID of each of the running `find` command and a 'run file' on master (e.g. `/run/distfind` containing 1 to begin with, under `inotifywait` watch). Then in your `find` script on each machine if the file is found, set contents of `master:/run/distfind` to zero (or delete it), triggering the reading of the host/PID list killing all other remote PIDs.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:bash], but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. You need to pick one or the other. Please don't assign 20 server names to 20 different variables like that. If you are using Bash, use an array. If your Bash is version 4 or later, use `mapfile` to populate that array. If not, then use a `while` loop (or just launch your jobs in the loop and skip using an array).

Comment: @MarkSetchell it takes around 15 seconds to find. There are 20 servers and there are 2 types of servers. I need to ssh and telnet to those servers and extract information. I can't add a script there. The scripts are running locally on my main server.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thanks. I will modify that. I actually used a loop to extract the names from the file first but it was executing the script in a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use something that can handle this for you: [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Termination-dependent-on-job-status). From the linked tutorial:

> If you are looking for success instead of failures, you can use success. This will finish as soon as the first job succeeds:

```
parallel -j2 --halt now,success=1 echo {}\; exit {} ::: 1 2 3 0 4 5 6
```

Output:

```
  1
  2
  3
  0
  parallel: This job succeeded:
  echo 0; exit 0
```

Comment: That's exactly where I was heading, but if it's just 200ms on each server, it's hardly worth the bother of killing the *"longer running"* processes - might as well let them run. Maybe OP will clarify my question on run-time...

Comment: @MarkSetchell In that case, it's hardly worth asking the question in the first place. My clue was in "actually it's more complex than that". Why do question askers always conceal things without providing a realistic proxy or characterization?

Comment: It takes around 15 seconds because it needs to ssh or telnet those servers. I can't add a script in the server, so the only way I found to execute something and then get the result was doing ssh or telnet (some of those servers won't allow ssh so I had to use telnet).

Comment: @NicoleC: `parallel` runs from a central system and can send a script or command to the remotes. [Examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Using-remote-computers).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by modifying your `find.sh` so that its return code depends on its success, that will let us identify a successful call more easily; for instance:

```
myValue=`sed -n '/VALUE/p' $tempfile | awk 'BEGIN{FS="="} {print substr($2, 8, length($2)-2)}'`
success=$?
echo "$myValue"
exit $success
```

To terminate all the `find.sh` processes spawned by your script you can use `pkill` with a Parent Process ID criteria and a command name criteria :

```
pkill -P $$ find.sh # $$ refers to the current process' PID
```

Note that this requires that you start the `find.sh` script directly rather than passing it as a parameter to `sh`. Normally that shouldn't be a problem, but if you have a good reason to call `sh` rather than your script, you can replace `find.sh` in the `pkill` command by `sh` (assuming you're not spawning other scripts you wouldn't want to kill).

Now that `find.sh` exits with success only when it finds the expected string, you can plug the two actions with `&&` and run the whole thing in background :

```
{ find.sh $value $c1 && pkill -P $$ find.sh; } &
```

The first occurrence of `find.sh` that terminates with success will invoke the `pkill` command that will terminate all others (those killed processes will have non-zero exit codes and therefore won't run their associated `pkill`).

Comment: Are you taking into account that each of the scripts will be running on a separate machine?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I assumed `find.sh` was executed on the local machine for each server and itself did invoke `ssh`. It doesn't really matter as long as the script that is locally executed spawns x copies of a single command that can return a significant exit code and be killed to interrupt the time-consuming operation

Comment: Killing the local scripts/local instances of ssh won't necessarily kill the processes on the remotes.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson won't killing the `ssh` client lead to the server eventually  detecting the disconnection and sending the `HUP` signal to the processes spawned on the remote machine, which will exit unless precautions were taken against?

Comment: Most likely yes.